# Using xpath select how do I get the value of this element in example?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

with this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<createTransactionResponse xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <refId>999999999</refId>
   <messages>
      <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
      <message>
         <code>I00001</code>
         <text>Successful.</text>
      </message>
   </messages>
   <transactionResponse>
      <responseCode>1</responseCode>
      <authCode>HH1D69</authCode>
      <avsResultCode>Y</avsResultCode>
      <cvvResultCode>P</cvvResultCode>
      <cavvResultCode>2</cavvResultCode>
      <transId>2228993425</transId>
      <refTransID />
      <transHash>916EE7527B17B62F62AA72B4C71F8322</transHash>
      <testRequest>0</testRequest>
      <accountNumber>XXXX0015</accountNumber>
      <accountType>MasterCard</accountType>
      <messages>
         <message>
            <code>1</code>
            <description>This transaction has been approved.</description>
         </message>
      </messages>
      <userFields>
         <userField>
            <name>MerchantDefinedFieldName1</name>
            <value>MerchantDefinedFieldValue1</value>
         </userField>
         <userField>
            <name>favorite_color</name>
            <value>blue</value>
         </userField>
      </userFields>
   </transactionResponse>
</createTransactionResponse>
```

I would like to get "resultCode", from here

```
<messages><resultCode>Ok</resultCode><message>
```

But the xpath I'm using does not give me the value of resultCode Ok.

What am I doing wrong?

--

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

                    string myXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><createTransactionResponse xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns=""AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd""><refId>999999999</refId><messages><resultCode>Ok</resultCode><message><code>I00001</code><text>Successful.</text></message></messages><transactionResponse><responseCode>1</responseCode><authCode>HH1D69</authCode><avsResultCode>Y</avsResultCode><cvvResultCode>P</cvvResultCode><cavvResultCode>2</cavvResultCode><transId>2228993425</transId><refTransID /><transHash>916EE7527B17B62F62AA72B4C71F8322</transHash><testRequest>0</testRequest><accountNumber>XXXX0015</accountNumber><accountType>MasterCard</accountType><messages><message><code>1</code><description>This transaction has been approved.</description></message></messages><userFields><userField><name>MerchantDefinedFieldName1</name><value>MerchantDefinedFieldValue1</value></userField><userField><name>favorite_color</name><value>blue</value></userField></userFields></transactionResponse></createTransactionResponse>";




 string myValue = XMLSelect(myXML, "createTransactionResponse/messages/message/resultCode");
        //myValue should = "Ok" but it does not :(

    }

    public static string XMLSelect(string _xmldoc, string _xpath)
    {
        string returnedValue = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        try
        {
            doc.LoadXml(_xmldoc);

            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            returnedValue = (string)doc.SelectNodes(_xpath)[0].InnerText; 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
        return returnedValue;
    }
```

Comment: It would be *much* easier to read your question if you'd format the XML into multiple lines so we didn't have to scroll horizontally like that. What *does* your existing code do? (Ideally having removed the exception "handling" which hides any problems.)

Comment: First problem: the XML string you've got isn't valid XML, because you've got backslashes in it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I fixed the xml, it now displays horizontally, and removed the backslash, however still not getting results. The method simply gets the value via xpath and returns the value.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that the XML you originally gave isn't valid. You're masking that by returning `""` whenever you encounter an exception, so you don't have any information any more.

So the first thing to do IMO is remove the spurious exception handling:

```
public static string XMLSelect(string _xmldoc, string _xpath)
{
    string returnedValue = string.Empty;
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(_xmldoc);        
    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    return (string)doc.SelectNodes(_xpath)[0].InnerText; 
}
```

Now, the problem with the XPath is that all the elements in your XML are in a namespace of `AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd` - so you'll probably want an `XmlNamespaceManager`. It's slightly tricky to separate that properly given the way that you've split the load from the XPath, but for the moment you could just introduce an alias of `ns` for the right namespace.

Next, your XPath is incorrect in that it looks for `message/resultCode`, when those two elements are peers. You don't want the `message` part.

Here's a short but complete program which fixes all those problems:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // As per the question
        string myXML = "...";
        string myValue = XMLSelect(myXML, "ns:createTransactionResponse/ns:messages/ns:resultCode");
        Console.WriteLine(myValue);
    }

    public static string XMLSelect(string _xmldoc, string _xpath)
    {
        string returnedValue = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(_xmldoc);        
        var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsm.AddNamespace("ns", "AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd");
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        return (string)doc.SelectNodes(_xpath, nsm)[0].InnerText;
    }
}
```

If you could use LINQ to XML instead, and simply work on the document instead of passing in the XML text and an XPath selector, it would be simpler:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd";
string code = (string) doc.Root
                          .Element(ns + "messages")
                          .Element(ns + "resultCode");
Console.WriteLine(code);
```

Comment: thanks...I took a slightly different approach, I first striped all namespaces, then I was able to get the values I needed :)

Comment: @001: It would be worth mentioning things like "I can change the XML at will" when you ask a question - I'd assumed that the structure of the XML was pretty much dictated to you. I'd still suggest using LINQ to XML and just handling the namespaces, personally...

Comment: no you can not change the XML at all, the XML is provided to the XMLSelect method via the input parameter _xmldoc, it could include the namespace mentioned above, or a different namespace or not include a namespace at all, XMLSelect method wouldnt know or care about the name space all it cares about is to find the element by xpath and return its value.

Comment: @001: But "find the element by xpath" includes the namespace. I would definitely *not* go down the root of stripping out namespaces within the `XMLSelect` method, personally. (Are you just doing a search and replace on the string? Ick.) Namespaces are there for a reason, and can be handled perfectly well - so I'd just use them.